# ionic framework =>react base project

Tags: ionic-framework

I am facing this issue in ionic 5 react base project when run in mobile

cmd=>npx cap add android

[error] The web directory (G:\ashwini\ionicprojects\reactproj\src) must contain a "index.html".
    It will be the entry point for the web portion of the Capacitor app.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

$ ionic build

And after:

$ npx cap add android

Answer (score 0):

run ionic build before you try to add the android platform